Is a reviewer allowed to delegate their peer reviewing task to someone else?
I have been wondering lately if a person, who has signed up as a peer reviewer at a journal (or multiple), can then delegate their duties to someone else (think senior scientist tells lower level researchers to do it)? What are the possible implications from doing so?
Reason for asking:
Me and my colleagues are getting peer reviewing tasks multiple times a year from our senior researcher, who always complains he doesn't have the time for it. Quite often, if taken seriously of course, such a task can be quite time consuming and collide with other tasks one has to do (think contractual obligations).
UPDATE
It has been pointed out that this is a complaint about being forced to do something I don't want to. That's not it and I should have been clearer on this. It is about whether it is actually allowed. @PsySp (thanks for the hint) points out one of several possible issues (I don't know what issues ergo the question) - plagiarism, if the peer reviewer does not fill the form for review submission in a way that makes it clear that they were not the reviewer but person X was.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Common, but it needs to be done the right way -- Contact the editor, and ask if it's OK.

As editor I would in that case want to invite the person who is "recommended" by the senior researcher directly, and deal with them directly. In the system the review should be associated with the person that actually did it, and also normally review tasks are confidential, so I don't think it's correct that the review by the "junior" person reaches the journal through the "senior" person. The "senior" person can recommend a reviewer to the editor but shouldn't handle the review of that person themselves.

@ChristianHennig -- absolutely.  There is every reason to make the new reviewer the "official" reviewer, and that's one major reason to do this through the editor.  The big bonus for the editor, of course, is the addition of a name to the potential referee list.

@ChristianHennig I've seen it done both ways. When recommending "mature" junior staff (e.g. excellent last year PhD students, postdocs, early career academics), then a full transfer is probably appropriate (often there are automatic "suggest an alternative reviewer" boxes you can fill out when refusing to review). However, I've also seen academics offer their PhD students to review, but then still read the paper themselves and "review their review" -- as this was done more as a guided exercise for that student, I think it was appropriate for the academic to stay on as the main reviewer.

(in all cases I agree that the editor should be notified of the situation and approve first)

@penelope OK, yes, I see that this makes sense with approval of the editor. the "junior" person needs to acknowledge any rules about confidentiality of course.

This advice may ruin the supervisor-student relationship when the supervisor finds out.

@Robin, how so?  There's zero need to hide anything from anybody, starting with when the supervisor recognizes the ms as appropriate for the trainee to review?  It's  done all the time

@ScottSeidman - But the world is not as simple/pure as you say. Most likely, such a person (like my supervisor) is a bully and knows well how to mentally bully to misuse of others. This is my (also some of my friends) experience.

@Robiin --- training students to serve as referees is an important job for a mentor.  Some would even say it's irresponsible not to train them.

Similar to @penelope's comment, I often make this explicitly part of the training I give to my PhD students (with the editors permission) - I get the student to review the paper in parallel with me and then discuss the differences/commonalities/issues with the student before combining to make the overall review.  Most students don't realise to begin with the main point of peer review is to make the paper better.

@Robin there is very little credit for reviewing papers - anybody that bullies a colleague for so small a benefit is not even acting rationally.  Having said which "Academic politics is the most vicious and bitter form of politics, because the stakes are so low" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayre%27s_law) I seem to have been very fortunate with my colleagues!

Speaking as someone who's sent thousands of reviewer invitations, it's not rare for reviewers to respond with "I can't review this paper but try my student/postdoc". Sometimes they don't say it's their student/postdoc, but it's possible to tell from Google (or from the fact that they've written papers together and those papers say they are at the same institution). It's not common, but also not rare.
It's definitely rare for a review to be returned with "this review was written in conjunction with my student/postdoc", however (I think I've seen it only once). I also cannot tell if the review was written by someone other than the invited person unless they say so, as well.
Broadly speaking there's nothing wrong with redirecting reviews to someone else, especially since it's desirable for graduate students to learn to do peer review. However, you definitely should tell the editor if someone else wrote the review. It's plagiarism otherwise. Furthermore, if the paper is controversial the editors will likely want to know that a reviewer is junior, and there's one publisher I'm aware of (MDPI) that simply will not accept reviews from people without PhDs.

reg. MDPI: very nice from them to avoid asking reviews from Nobel prizes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Kilby :)

A review is a personal invitation from someone to a certain person.
If someone proposes to you, do you say yes and then send someone else to the next date with this someone?
Usually when you refuse to review you are invited to suggest other possible reviewers.
Refuse to review and suggest to the editor (either with the automated form or per email) the lower level researchers as reviewers.

The other side of the coin is this: if someone that is not the editor invites you to do a review, and then you do not get any thank you note or at least acknowledgment of receival of the peer review directly by the journal/editor, you can be 99% sure that the same someone that asked you to perform the review is taking credit for having done the review.

This is one-sided. I wrote reviews for my advisor and toke it as the basis for his review. He threw out a couple of comments and added valueable remarks by himself. I learned to write better reviews and to concentrate on important stuff. I think nobody got real credit, I perceived it as a win-win.

@usr1234567 "I think nobody got real credit" your advisor may have got free access for 1-month to all the publication from the editor, or something like that. Even if it was only an automated "thank you" mail from the editorial system, that "thank you" went fully to your advisor, not to you.
Did you learn something? it is a side effect, there is no need to do free work to learn something. Since your advisor modified, but did not reject your work, it means it was of decent quality ---> you did some work! I agree that there may not be a way to share the credit of a review (see other answers).

It happens, and it can be a good thing and bad thing.
As to how it can be a good thing: PhD students are supposed to learn how academia works. An advisor can first write a review together with a student, explaining what her/his/their choices are, for the second stage let the student write first drafts which she/he/they than review, and finally refuse request to review certain papers but tell the editor that they know someone (the student) who can write that review instead.
As to how it can be bad thing: it can be just so the senior person gets to do less work.

"Review together with" doesn't mean delegating the authority and the final decision-making, just some of the work.

Absolutely, it is the second stage that can be interpreted as delegation. Especially when the first stage was successful and not much review by the advisor is needed.

In my subfield of computer science (computer vision / machine learning), this is fairly common. It is probably connected to how quickly the field has been growing over the past few years (for example, the number of submissions to CVPR has tripled over the past five years).
It is then very common for senior researchers to get a large reviewing load, which is often partly delegated to students and other junior researchers. However, there are now mechanisms in place to give due credit to such reviewers; for example, some conferences have a field in their review submission form that allows one to specify if someone else performed the review that they were invited for, so that the actual reviewer can be acknowledged in the list of reviewers.

Even though it's a conference, you could consider adding this information as an answer to Are there major non-APS/AIP journals that do not practice confidential peer review?.

@Anyon It might be the phrasing in the title of the question you link ("Which journals/confs do not practice confidential peer review"), but on first glance I wouldn't find this relevant. "Not practicing confidential peer review" would, in my opinion, mean that the journal publishes the manuscript publicly, free for anybody to access, while still under review. Allowing people to delegate to junior colleagues is... not quite that

@penelope Maybe the title isn't the best possible phrasing.

I'm a bit surprised that I haven't found any answer mentioning the concept of Secondary Reviewer, a concept which exists in my field (Computer Science - NLP).
For example, here's an excerpt from the reviewing guidelines of ACL (emphasis mine):

Q: Can I designate a secondary or substitute reviewer for ARR?
A: An assigned reviewer may wish to recruit another individual—often a mentee—to help with the review. This is called a secondary reviewer. You can involve a secondary reviewer by coordinating the review offline and submitting it in OpenReview as your own. In this case, we encourage you to leave a confidential note to the action editor indicating who the secondary reviewer was (see the question above for how to do this). However, they will not be acknowledged in OpenReview as a reviewer.
Alternatively, if you wish to hand over full reviewing duties to a colleague or mentee, you can ask your action editor to reassign the paper to a substitute reviewer in your stead. They will be acknowledged in OpenReview as a reviewer. You will no longer be listed as a reviewer of the paper and will be unable to access the paper and its reviews in the system.

So at least in this field, it's not uncommon to delegate reviewing task to a mentee (as explicitly mentioned as an example in the ACL guideline above).
But as always, this depends on the specific journal/conference's reviewing guidelines, so do check your journal/conference guidelines whether they allow such secondary reviewers.

Some journals (e.g., APS ones in physics) have a checkbox in the referee response form saying something like 'I prepared this report on my own'. If you don't tick it, you need to add details of anyone who helped you.
This suggests to me that some journals (and certainly APS) are fine with referees using help, so long as it is disclosed.
